# Module loader error: "Manifest file specifies an unrecognized package type" (SuiteCRM)

Tags: module, sugarcrm, suitecrm, turkish

When I'm trying to load language pack ([turkish](https://crowdin.com/project/suitecrmtranslations/tr#)) on admin/module loader tab

I'm getting the following error:

***Manifest file specifies an unrecognized package type:'dilpaketi'***

Also I tried different language pack which is portuguese I didn't get an error for this language. This error for turkish language.

How can I solve this problem, please help me.

[image: error image]

Comment: I solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the turkish language pack "manifest.php" file is wrong. I edit this file outside of zip and replaced this file in the zip file. then I tried once again, it was successful.

translators made big mistake for that.

manifest.php file should be like this:

```
    <?PHP
/******************************************
 * SuiteCRM Translations
 * @URL: https://crowdin.com/project/suitecrmtrans
 * @author SuiteCRM Community via Crowdin
 ******************************************/
$manifest = array( 
    'name' => 'Turkce (Turkiye)',
    'description' => 'Çeviri: www.crowdin.com/project/suitecrmtranslations',
    'type' => 'langpack',
    'is_uninstallable' => 'Yes',
    'acceptable_sugar_versions' =>
          array (),
    'acceptable_sugar_flavors' =>
          array('CE'),
    'author' => 'SuiteCRM Community',
    'version' => '7.9.1.0',
    'published_date' => '2017-06-19',
      );
$installdefs = array(
    'id'=> 'tr_TR',
    'image_dir'=>'<basepath>/images',
    'copy' => array(
    array('from'=> '<basepath>/include','to'=>'include'),
    array('from'=> '<basepath>/modules','to'=>'modules'),
    array('from'=> '<basepath>/install','to'=>'install'),
   )
 );
?>
```